# Как передать переменную в объект?

Tags: javascript

```js
var booked = document.getElementById('booked');
booked = +booked.innerText;

var hotel = {
  name: "Santor",
  rooms: 20,
  checkAvailability: function(booked) {
    return this.rooms - booked;
  }
}
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability());
```

```html
<p id="booked">12</p>
```

Выскакивает NaN. Ожидал получить 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сейчас это не работает, потому что при вызове: `hotel.checkAvailability()` ничего не передается, и, следовательно, значение параметра `booked` внутри функции будет `undefined`.

---

Чтобы это заработало - нужно **передать** booked при вызове функции.

```js
var booked = document.getElementById('booked');
booked = +booked.innerText;

var hotel = {
  name: "Santor",
  rooms: 20,
  checkAvailability: function(booked) {
    return this.rooms - booked;
  }
}
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability(booked));
```

```html
<p id="booked">12</p>
```

Либо убрать сам параметр, в этом случае будет использовать глобальная переменная:

```js
var booked = document.getElementById('booked');
booked = +booked.innerText;

var hotel = {
  name: "Santor",
  rooms: 20,
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - booked;
  }
}
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability());
```

```html
<p id="booked">12</p>
```